# How to get unique values when restricted to select * using SQL

Tags: sql, unique

I have a table that gets a new record every 30 seconds. I have a need to know the most current record for each user and the timestamp value.

I wrote the following query:

```
select created_user,  MAX(created_date)
from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw
Group by created_user
```

It gets me exactly what I want. The problem is that the application I need to input this into predefines part of the select statement for me (trying to be helpful).

So it is MANDATORY that the query starts

```
select * from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw WHERE
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to make this work

Comment: Rewrite your application. It shouldn't restrict you. Otherwise you will have difficulties with all queries :)

Comment: That's not always a viable option (as a matter of fact, it almost never is...)

Comment: This is off the shelf software and re-writing is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM  (SELECT created_user,  MAX(created_date)'created_date'
                     FROM gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw
                     GROUP BY created_user) b
              WHERE gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw.created_user = b.created_user
                 AND gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw.created_date = b.created_date)
```

Comment: This returns 897 records, I am expecting the result to be 2 records as I only have 2 users hitting this table right now.

Comment: That's odd, 897 records for the 2 users?  It works on my test data.

Comment: Do the records all have the same user/date combinations?  If so, is there another field you could use to differentiate?

Comment: You are right, the created_date field had repeat values, luckily, there were other datestamp fields I could use!! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick solution: Use it as subquery

```
select created_user,  MAX(created_date)
from 
(
select * from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw WHERE 1=1 //append this
)
Group by created_user
```

Notice that I added `1=1` which will always be evaluated to true to handle your `Where` clause.

Comment: does the op want his query as the starting point and not as the subquery?

Comment: The select * from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw WHERE HAS to be the starting point and cannot be altered because there is no way within the application to change this, it is hard coded.

Comment: @user1074006 so you cant write and run SQL? I think you need to clarify your question more and explain about your environment

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw
WHERE (something that returns no records)
```

Ignore whatever the first query returns, then just do your own thang.

```
select created_user,  MAX(created_date)
from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw
Group by created_user
```

Comment: The select * from gisadmin.FORESTRY_LOCATIONLOG_vw WHERE HAS to be the starting point and cannot be altered because there is no way within the application to change this, it is hard coded.

Comment: @user1074006 What if you just define a WHERE statement that returns no records, ignore that part of the query, then just run a separate one?

Comment: maybe a union of both? you need to make sure you are pulling in the same set of columns from the bottom query